# Automatically convert to the right class when building a data.table object in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I am frequently building some count stats using `table`.

My intention is to build a simple `data.table / data_frame / tibble` with 2 columns.

Here is an example:

```
tbl <- structure(c(61L, 66L, 114L, 72L, 127L, 45L, 66L, 67L, 70L), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

What I do is `data.table(df) %>% mutate(V1 = as.integer(V1))`

Is there any option within `data.table / data_frame` to "convert" to the "right" class?
You have this in the `separate` function (`convert = TRUE`).

Please advise.

Comment: maybe look at the function `type.convert` from `base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function in `readr` called `parse_guess`, which tries to "guess" the right type. The easiest solution is to use `mutate_all` to convert all column to the right class:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
tbl <- structure(c(61L, 66L, 114L, 72L, 127L, 45L, 66L, 67L, 70L), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
  c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")), .Names = ""), class = "table")


res <- data.table(tbl) %>% mutate_all(readr::parse_guess)
glimpse(res)
```